# Task Module in Teams not working in IOS Using Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am showing the Task module on Click on the adaptive card button. It is working fine in the Teams Desktop application and in android but it is not working in IOS.

This is the iframe that I am displaying on Task Module on the button click and a form is showing on the Task module in Android Teams app and Desktop app.

```
<iframe width="850px" height="725px" src="https://forms.office.com/Pages/****" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" max-width="100%" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" scrolling="no" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How to make it work in IOS?

### edit:-

I am using Iphonex 13.3.1 and Teams app version 2.0.9.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of iOS app are you using? Could you please try update it?

Comment: Hello @Gousia-MSFT, I have updated my question

Comment: Does it load inside Teams web browser? Could you please see if there are any console logs?

Comment: Hello @Gousia-MSFT, Yes it is loading in Web and desktop app but in IOS Teams app task module itself not opening.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the iOS client. We are checking this internally.